# How to check in sql if a table has got only one column?

Tags: php, mysql

In my php code, I would like to remove columns from a table like this :

```
function delete_table_column_db( $table_name, $column_attrs ){
    global $wpdb;
    $res = $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE " . $table_name . " DROP " . $column_attrs['name'] );

    if( $res === false ){
        error_log( sprintf("The column %s could not be deleted for the table %s", $column_attrs['name'], $table_name ) );
    }
}
```

But this function makes an error if the table has got only one column :

```
ERROR 1090 (42000): You can't delete all columns with ALTER TABLE; use DROP TABLE instead
```

So I would like to `DROP TABLE` if it´s the last column of the table.
For that, I need to check if it´s the last table column.
Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Please be aware that adding or removing columns from a table is a very expensive and disruptive DB operation, and not something that should be done outside of maintenance operations.

Comment: Dropping columns or altering table definitions as part of an app is usually a good sign that the design is not right in the first place.  Having an evolving database structure is also a good way of making code fail when the underlying table suddenly changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of columns in a table, we will need to use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html). Following solution will work only if the user has access to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables.

You can get the total number of columns in a table as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS no_of_columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$your_table_name' AND 
      TABLE_SCHEMA = '$your_database_name'
```

So you can use this query first, get the number of columns. If it is more than 1, then you can proceed with the `ALTER TABLE .. DROP COLUMN` query.

Some of the noteworthy columns in the `information_schema.columns` table are:

> `TABLE_SCHEMA` - The name of the schema (database) to which the table
>   containing the column belongs.
>
> `TABLE_NAME` - The name of the table containing the column.
>
> `COLUMN_NAME` - The name of the column.

Comment: Thank you ! What means `AS no_of_columns` ?

Comment: @J.BizMai it is just an alias for the count being received from the query. you can refer to this alias to get the value after `query()`.

Answer (score 0):

The complete code based on @Madhur Bhaiya answer :

```
function delete_table_column_db( $table_name, $column_attrs ){
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS no_of_columns FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '{$table_name}'"
    $check_column_count = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
    $nbr_columns = (int) $check_column_count[0]['no_of_columns'];
    if( $check_column_count === 1 ){
        $res = $wpdb->query( "DROP TABLE {$table_name}"  );
    }else{
        $res = $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE {$table_name} DROP {$column_attrs['name']}" );
    }
    if( $res === false ){
        error_log( sprintf("The column %s could not be deleted for the table %s", $column_attrs['name'], $table_name ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $wpdb->query('SELECT * FROM '. $tablename);  
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount(); 
if($row_count==1){
 //drop table  
} 
else{
 //alter table drop columns
}
```

Hope it helps.